# Missing leading slash in Backbone route fails to deliver despite docs suggesting the opposite

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

## Q:

Should I change my href attributes to be relative or should I define routes with leading slashes?
(*Why do the Backbone docs suggest no leading slashes?*)

## Background:

The Backbone docs clearly *suggest* the following:

> Note that you'll want to avoid using a **leading slash** in your route definitions…

Now, I have these routes defined for a test:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "index/": "logMe",
    "/clients/": "logMe"
  },

  logMe: function (page) {
    console.log(page);
  }
});
```

Calling `router.navigate($(this).attr('href'), {trigger: true});` on `click`, the route is captured fine for `/clients/` but not for `index`. (Adding a leading `/` to the *index* route fixes this).

The `href="…"` strings I'm passing are all starting from the domain root (`href="/index/"` & `href="/clients/"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "href" value passed in is *matched* to the route property names. If your "href" values start with a slash, then your route properties have to as well.

Note that in all the examples in the Backbone docs, the fragment values do not start with a slash.

Answer (score 3):

The backbone docs recommend avoiding leading slashes because they will break if you use `pushState: true`.

For example:

```
routes: {
    "/clients/": "logMe"
}
```

Gives a hash URL of `http://example.com/#/clients/`, but a pushState URL of `http://example.com//clients/`, which is clearly going to fail.

Using a prefix of something like `!/` will work:

```
routes: {
    "!/clients/": "logMe"
}
```

This gives `http://example.com/#!/clients/` and `http://example.com/!/clients/`, respectively.

Also note that leading slashes don't work with `router.navigate`. `router.navigate('/clients/')` is automatically stripped, resulting in a URL of `#clients/`, not `#/clients/`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This has been my experience as well.